# Else if statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm a beginner to java... if statements followed by else if statements are evaluated in order until one that evaluates to true is found, and I've seen many examples of this. But in this program, both statements (the if and the else if) are evaluated. Why?

```
public int centeredAverage(int[] nums) {

    int[] nums = {1, 1, 5, 5, 10, 8, 7};

    int sum = 0;
    int centered = 0;
    int min = nums[0];
    int max = nums[0];
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if (nums[i] < min){
            min = nums[i];
        } else if (nums[i] > max){
            max = nums[i];
        }
        sum += nums[i];
        centered = ((sum-max-min)/(nums.length-2));
    }

    return centered;
}
```

Comment: Its always excute else block. wats wrong??

Comment: Nothing really. I'm just trying to fully understand how the if and else if work by writing many different codes. So, you're saying that after the "if" is evaluated, then the "else if" will be always evaluated? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look like both `if` and `else` will be evaluated.  Can you give us some output?

Comment: if your if statement is evaluted then your else if or else statment will never executed.

Comment: The else if is evaluated and because it is true, it is executed. That's how I obtain the max value, and then I can subtract sum-min-max. If the else if is not executed, then I wouldn't be able to get the max value.

Comment: i agree with you buddy but here only your else if executed not if.....then what is your proble?? if your if statement is false then it goes further to check like else if....and so on.....if no statement are true then it execute else statement if it is there.....so in your case only else if executed.

Comment: The output for this will be 5

Comment: No Pratik, the if is also executed, that's why I'm asking the question here. Why both are executed? I know they are both executed because I run the program in debug mode and can see it, and also that's how I get the value for min which I then use to subtract from sum.

Comment: I believe I found the answer on my own. They are both executed because after "if" evaluates to true several times, then it evaluates to false. And that's when the "else if" is evaluated. So that's why both of them are evaluated. That's my logic so far...

Comment: Makes sense to me.  Why didn't I think of that. :P

Comment: The if and else if are in a for loop. In each loop the if gets checked if that fails then the else if gets checked. You are doing the checks multiple times, sometimes the if is true and sometimes the if is false and the else if is true, both the if and else if can be false.

Comment: I'll just be banging my head on the desk.  Don't mind me.

Comment: hahaha that's a good one CandiedOrange! I'm a beginner! This code finds the min value of the array, then the max value, then add the entire array and subtract the min and max value from it and finally does the division to get the centered value.

Comment: Seriously, am I on candid camera?

Answer (score 3):

Because they're in a loop that changes `i` and so changes `nums[i]` and so changes what `if`'s are true.

Answer (score 0):

Your passing in array of doubles by reference called nums and the defining an array of the same name in the method which seems odd. Also your start index for your for loop should be 1

Comment: The start index should be zero, not 1.  This is Java.

Comment: I believe dmonarch is offering an optimization since min and nums[0] start out the same.  This is wrong only because it's not something to confuse a newbie programmer with. :)  He's right about the name `nums` as well.  You don't give your kids the same name for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Im guessing this is the same problem from codingbat, next time copy and paste the problem desciption for others!

public int centeredAverage(int[] nums) {
       Arrays.sort(nums); //sorts the array smallest to biggest
       int total = 0;
       //nums is already sorted, so the smallest value is at spot 0
       //and the biggest value is at the end.
       for(int a = 1; a < nums.length - 1; a++){ //avoid the first and last numbers
       total += nums[a];
       }
       return total / (nums.length - 2); //need ( ) so we can substract 2 first

       //Another way could simply sum all the elements then subtract from that sum
       //the biggest and smallest numbers in the array, then divide by nums.length- 2, it is a 
       //little more complex, but allows a for : each loop.
    }

But for you, well since you are a beginner, restate your strategy (algorithm), find the smallest and biggest numbers in the array, subtract that out of the sum of all elements in the array then divide that number by nums.length - 2, since we are ignoring 2 numbers.
```

Answer (score -1):

Working of If statement followed by else-if is fine here. We are getting expected result here. Both the statements if and else-if are not executed. Only that statement is executed which comes TRUE as per logic.
Here we can identify the working of the program using "System.out.println". Code and console output is given below...

```
    int[] nums = {1, 1, 5, 5, 10, 8, 7};

    int sum = 0;
    int centered = 0;
    int min = nums[0];
    int max = nums[0];
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] >  min)
        {
           min = nums[i];

            System.out.println("inside first if:  " + i);
            // taking value of i in SOP to get the iteration value 

        } 
      else if (nums[i] > max)
        {
            max = nums[i];
        }

       sum += nums[i];
        centered = ((sum-max-min)/(nums.length-2));

        System.out.println("inside else if:  " + i);
         // taking value of i in SOP to get the iteration value 

    }

    System.out.println("centered value "
            + " " + centered);
```

You can make a good usage of SOP in every program to get the execution order.